# logstash conf - log line starting with [ and ending with ] not shown in kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

recently I ve been working with filebeat -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana setup

I have 2 servers:
1. server running cca 20 containers (each producing different logs) and filebeat
2. server running logstash, elasticsearch and kibana

circa 9 of my containers have logs starting with "[" and anding with "]" and all those containers are not shown in kibana. **I assume that the brackets are the reason why my logstash config does not accept the message and hence the log line is not shown in kibana???**

when I restart container it produces log message, something like "Container started" - this log line dodes not start/end with [ or ] -> This line was shown in kibana correctly.   So most likely the brackets are the issue.

**Please could you help me to setup my logstash conf file so it does accept/send logs starting/ending with [ ] to kibana ?** Please if you can help, share exact config text as I am not very skilled with the syntax

I am sending you my logstash config as it is looking now:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    host => "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} \<%{IP:hostAddress}\> - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{DATA:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}\" %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:bytes}" }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => localhost
  }
}
```

Here I am adding example of log lined produced by one of the containers:

```
[2018-11-29 18:12:54,322: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//
[2018-11-29 18:12:54,335: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-11-29 18:12:55,431: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync with 1 nodes
```

My config is now setup mainly for nginx container, if you have time you can also help me to create config for the above log. But in this post I mainly want to know how to process the [ and ] which are in the log so it is send to kibana.

Thank you guys very much in advance, I hope I will find help here as I am pretty lost with that. Thank you

Comment: The pattern in your grok filter will only match a specific format of log, but I would expect all logs to make it to elastic through this pipeline, they would just have '_grokparsefailure' tags

Comment: For improving and creating grok patterns try using an online debugger (I have no affiliation with this tool, beyond using it alot) http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Comment: Debugging your pipeline can be done by starting using a stdout output and a stdin input to test that logs are flowing through

Comment: If logs sent into stdin input come out via stdout output after passing through your pipeline, then logstash may not even be receiving the logs and you should look to your beat for the cause.